# A moderator put my self-answered question on hold and did not return to review it after it was edited

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

A moderator put my self-answered question on hold and did not seemed to return to review it even though after I've edited my question.  How to tell if the moderator had returned to reviewed it, especially after the editing was done in accordance with the initial reason for putting on hold ("unclear what you're asking")?

My posted question was "How to integrate Xdebug 2.2.3 (PHP 5.53) with PhpStorm 7.0.  I thought that I could share my experiences with the community because I couldn't find similar answers elsewhere that pertained to the specific config/system that I was using.  I detailed very specific steps on how to achieve the answer and there were also a few good authors who helpfully added their comments and links to relevant and related answer before the post was closed.

I urge for moderators to review this as I believe that the answers could benefit many people with similar questions.  Please review the post again.  Thank you.

ps: the link is at [How to integrate Xdebug 2.2.3 (PHP 5.53) with PhpStorm 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730943/how-to-integrate-xdebug-2-2-3-php-5-53-with-phpstorm-7-0/20731242#20731242)

Comment: @Pëkka Since you seem to think the question is clear, what is the question that is being asked here?  I personally have no idea what question is being asked there.

Comment: @Servy I agree the question's wording needs to be changed. I made a (somewhat brutal) suggestion, feel free to roll back if you don't like it Dale

Comment: @Pëkka Then why vote to reopen it, if you feel that, in its current state, it is not an understandable question?

Comment: @Servy because it's *very* easy to turn it into an understandable question by simply removing the introduction. See my edit

Comment: @Pëkka And now I'd say it's "too broad", doesn't show a minimal understanding of the problem, shows no effort/research, doesn't explain the problem, etc.  It's still nowhere near a state appropriate for reopening.

Comment: @Servy there's plenty of self-answered questions that have this format.

Comment: @Pëkka And they're very poor quality questions that should be downvoted/closed until they are improved.  The existance of other poor quality questions doesn't make asking another any more appropriate.

Comment: @Servy I guess the question then is - are self-answered tutorials on topic or not? Because to me, there's no meaningful way how this question could be "improved". I'm not sure whether a clear community consensus exists.

Comment: @Pëkka It's always been rather clear when dealing with self answered questions that questions should be evaluated independently of their answers, that posting an answer with your question doesn't magically remove all expectations of quality from a question.  The question should be evaluated as if it were asked without an answer.  If you wouldn't leave the question open without the answer, it shouldn't be left open with the answer.

Comment: @Servy certainly true, and I usually try to live by that. But it can lead to some bizarre behaviour of making up a midway problem at random which isn't as useful to future users as a detailed description of the problem to be solved

Comment: @RichardTingle Which is why I so often say that self-answered questions are very hard to do well, and I try to avoid suggesting it as a practice.  In this case here, there are so many problems beyond just that though.  In my eyes the core problem is simply too broad here, even if every other problem is addressed, making it a poor choice for an SO question.  It probably belongs as a blog post or tutorial on some non-Q/A site.

Comment: @Servy I agree with pretty much all of that. It is just in general I would rather that with self answered we interpretated "minimum understanding" as "show very clearly the problem to be solved" rather than "show what you tried"

Comment: @RichardTingle Sure, but this question still doesn't do that, and honestly that problem isn't one of my top concerns with this question, or most self answered questions for that matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your post didn't seem to be a question, which is why it was put on hold. It still doesn't seem to ask a question.

Currently it reads more like an introduction to the answer. This is not how self answered questions are supposed to be, you should ask a question as if you don't already know the answer and then answer as if you are not the question asker

### Pëkka's edit

Pëkka's edit has now introduced a question into your question and removed the extraneous answer parts.  It is certainly an improvement but you should not use it as a model on how to do these questions.  Ideally more detail as to the problem (not it's solution) would be included in the question.

Comment: @Pëkka Thank you for the edit.  By making it concise, I can see how the format could better serve its purpose.  I can relate to the more straight forward questions style because, in other circumstances during my search pertaining to other topics, SO's efficient questions style did help. In addition, framing Q&As as if it had originated from separate contributors helps make it more relevant as (i) the questions are framed to echo people's actual questions during their searches, and (ii) answers more robust as the mental model is now that there could be other possible answers.

Answer (score 13):

Other answers have tackled the issue of what is wrong with your question. I want to tackle another thing. You seem to feel that there is just one moderator, and that this moderator, after closing your question, is obliged to notice it was edited and return to the question to revisit the decision. This is wrong.

There are thousands of users with "vote to close" privileges. When 5 of them (or one diamond mod) vote to close a question, it goes on hold. When it is edited, the close voters are not notified. It is not normal for them to come back and check on questions they closed, either. Instead the question is put into a re-open queue, where a typically different pool of users can vote to re-open it if the edits sufficed.

If you received comments on your question, you can @-reply the commenters to tell them you've fixed the issue they commented about, but this is not a general strategy. You could also comment on your own question asking for more information about why it is on hold and what still needs to be fixed. Generally someone will take a moment to give you their opinion.

Comment: @JDB last sentence of the second paragraph.

Comment: Saw that, but not sure it's clear from what you wrote that edited posts are *automatically* submitted to the reopen queue.

Comment: @KateGregory I have a better understanding now.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

First, mods themselves are very busy handling flags and whatnot, and can't be expected to return to every post they close whenever it's edited.

Also, your question isn't really a question. You need to *ask a question*. As it is, it feels like a tutorial with a split in the middle. Move the question to the question, and *all* answer stuff to the answer. Then we can reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

I can venture to guess that your post was closed because even after your edit, it is not adhering to the SO guidelines,  namely it does not follow the question and answer format clearly. This is not a site to showcase tutorials, unless said tutorial is part of a answer.

Comment: `unless said tutorial is part of a answer` and even then, having a tutorial in an answer is generally a sign that the question is "too broad".

Comment: @Servy: Not unless that tutorial is simply explaining the steps to resolve the question. That is the point I am making. I guess am using the term tutorial loosely here to describe steps to follow.

Comment: I'm not saying they're universally disallowed, merely that if it takes an entirely tutorial to answer a question, there are pretty good odds that the question is too broad.  By and large, SO isn't a good place for tutorials.  They don't fit the Q/A model very well.